# Producing a list

Tags: list-manipulation

```
Table[x, {i, 5}]
```

In mathematica 9 this results in `{x,x,x,x,x}`, but in v10 it's `{1,1,1,1,1}` . How do I produce `{x,x,x,x,x}` in BOTH versions? 
I actually want one of length 151

Comment: I don't think that's changed in v10 (in fact, I confirmed it).  Did you Clear[x] before you ran your code in v10?

Comment: You must have made an assignment `x = 1`, before you evaluated your `Table` expression.

Answer (score 2):

`ConstantArray[x,151]` should work for you as well.